Query about Event Camera
So generally when we try to use the camera module to get the image data, it publishers at regular intervals even if there is no change in the environment. But I have recently come across this Event Cameras which only publishes data (I am not sure if it's right word) only if there is an change in surrounding environment. So how does ROS handle this when there is no fixed publishing rate from the hardware?
Sorry if I got something mixed-up, I am still beginner in ROS and trying to understand the overall picture of the pub-sub system.
Thank you.
